# Bind Class property to a nested object property

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api

this is my problem

i have a class in my dataModel class A

```
public class A
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string address { get; set; }
    public string addressType { get; set; }

    public A()
    {
        this.name = "";
        this.address = "";
        this.addressType = "";
    }
}
```

in the fron-end application i have a Json like This

```
    {
       name : "Jean",
       address : "Golden Road St #122",
       addressType : {
           id: "ABC-ID-ADD",
           description: "Street Adress"
       }
    }
```

in the back end i have this

```
        [HttpPost]
        [Route("save")]
        public IHttpActionResult save([FromBody] A a)
        {
            // a.name == "Jean"
            // a.address == "Golden Road St #122"
            // but in this point a.addressType is null, but i want a.addressType == "ABC-ID-ADD"
            return Ok();
        }
```

there is a way that i can map the **"id"** property of **"addressType"** JSON to the property **"addressType"** of the class A?

thanks in advance

Answer (score -1):

change the json in the front end

```
{
   name : "Jean",
   address : "Golden Road St #122",
   addressType : "ABC-ID-ADD"
}
```